# Dialogflow - Google Assistant: Show suggestions in multiple lines

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I want to show a list of suggestions to the user, and as expected I do it like:

```
new Suggestions('option 1', 'option 2', 'option 3', '...');
```

But the problem is that this way the suggestions are shown in a single row and the user will have to do horizontal scroll to reach all suggestions.

Instead, I would prefer to organize the suggestions in a table view in order to have multiple rows.

I thought I could get through this using this approach but it doesn't seem to work:

```
new Table({
    dividers: true,
         columns: ['header 1', 'header 2', 'header 3'],
         rows: [
           [new Suggestions('opt 1-1'), new Suggestions('opt 1-2'), new Suggestions('opt 1-3')],
           [new Suggestions('opt 2-1'), new Suggestions('opt 2-2'), new Suggestions('opt 2-3')],
         ]
})
```

Does anyone know any other way how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not really a way to show suggestions within a table. You could show a table of plain text, inviting the user to say one of the options, but you won't get the interactive widgets.

The idea of the suggestion chips is to *suggest* but not mandate a handful of potential things that the user might say to continue the conversation, and the horizontal row is meant to highlight the most frequent.